# Android: How to make a circular shape with one corner in XML?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I need to describe the following shape in xml for an android project.
I know there is the retangle with rounded corners, but how could I achieve that rectangle has only one corner and the rest rounded?

[image: the shape I need in xml]

This is not going to be used as a text speech bubble like people have asked about  in so many questions. 
I just want to use the shape as a background for one line of text. 
The shape color should easily be changable dynamically.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add it in a file in the drawable folder:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" /></shape>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my issue. I got it work on my android device which is important. However, Android Studio won't preview this correctly since "Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect."

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
             android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create an xml file in the drawable folder and set this xml as background of your view. It should work like charm.
Let me know if you find some issue.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
 /></shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I change the shape color programmatically then?

Comment: Create multiple xml files and at runtime, call setBackground(id) and provide resource id to this call. This will work.

Comment: If you are talking about changing color when button is pressed, you can use selector tag in above xml for different states.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought it was possible to reuse the xml. so if I want to use this  shape in several colors, I need to create a xml file for each color, right? So I can't let's say pick a color at runtime and fill the shape with that color.